# Installing unison on Redhat

Tags: redhat, unison

I can't seem to manage to install unison on red hat 7.2

tried multiple tutorials such as this one
http://www.tecmint.com/file-synchronization-in-linux-using-unison/

I Have epel enabled
But:

```
sudo yum install unison
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install unison
```

Both give me:

```
No package unison available.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tutorial is completely wrong. (And that's one of the sites for which this seems to be very frequently true.)

In EPEL, the unison package names include a version number, such as `unison227` and `unison240`. This is because, for whatever reason, the various versions of unison are not compatible with each other, so the version must be the same on all systems to be synchronized.

On EPEL 7, only `unison240` is available, and at present it's in the EPEL testing repo and hasn't yet moved to stable. So that is the base name of the packages you will install (e.g. `unison240`, `unison240-text` and/or `unison240-gtk`).

```
yum --enablerepo=epel --enablerepo=epel-testing install unison240
```

Comment: You are awesome! Any hints how I could have discovered it by myself? (to learn the technique)

Comment: You can do a `yum search unison` to find anything with unison in the name or description.  If you didn't have epel-testing you wouldn't see that at all and would have to dig further in to other repos, perhaps searching on google for unison repo references.

Comment: @Boaz Probably not the way I did. First, I've tried unison before, so I was already familiar with how it was packaged. I run a mirror of CentOS, EPEL and Fedora, so it was trivial to `find /srv/www/mirrors -name unison*` and see what came up.

Comment: `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`
`rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`